# SQL inner join multiple tables and do calculation

Tags: sql

Hi I want to find out the top 3 products that have the most growth in revenue and the top 3 products that have the most decrease in revenue by comparing products revenue in Oct 1996 and Sep 1996.

The dataset I used is at [w3c's online platform](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/trysql.asp?filename=trysql_select_all), the needed data are in these 3 tables: 'Orders', 'OrderDetails', 'Products'. Ideally I want to be able to run the code on the w3c platform.

So far I can output Orders data in Sep 1996. How can I insert Oct 1996 Orders data to it and calculate revenue changes ?

```
SELECT 
  od.ProductID, 
  MIN(o.OrderDate) as SalesStart, 
  MAX(o.OrderDate) as SalesEnd, 
  SUM(od.Quantity) as SoldQty, 
  SUM(od.Quantity * p.Price) as SoldAmt, 
  SUM(od.Quantity * p.Price) * 1.0 / 
  (
    SELECT SUM(odAll.Quantity * pAll.Price) 
    FROM OrderDetails odAll 
    INNER JOIN Orders as oAll 
      ON oAll.OrderID = odAll.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products as pAll
      ON odAll.ProductID =  pAll.ProductID
    WHERE oAll.OrderDate LIKE '1996-09%') as PortionInTotalSales
FROM Orders as o
INNER JOIN OrderDetails as od
  ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products as p
  ON od.ProductID =  p.ProductID  
WHERE o.OrderDate LIKE '1996-09%'
GROUP BY od.ProductID
```

Comment: Use BETWEEN statement in the WHERE clause: WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-01' and '1996-10-31'
https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

Comment: You should tell us which version of SQL the W3schools platform is using.  Every database can have slightly different syntax.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I might go for a union here.  Here is a query which should work for MySQL, but not necessarily other databases.

```
(
    SELECT
        0 AS marker
        pAll.ProductID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN oAll.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-10-01' AND '1996-10-31'
                 THEN odAll.Quantity * pAll.Price ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN oAll.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-01' AND '1996-09-30'
                 THEN odAll.Quantity * pAll.Price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_diff
    FROM OrderDetails odAll 
    INNER JOIN Orders oAll 
        ON oAll.OrderID = odAll.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products pAll
        ON odAll.ProductID =  pAll.ProductID
    GROUP BY pAll.ProductID
    ORDER BY sales DESC
    LIMIT 3
)
UNION ALL
(
    SELECT
        1
        pAll.ProductID,
        SUM(CASE WHEN oAll.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-10-01' AND '1996-10-31'
                 THEN odAll.Quantity * pAll.Price ELSE 0 END) -
        SUM(CASE WHEN oAll.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-01' AND '1996-09-30'
                 THEN odAll.Quantity * pAll.Price ELSE 0 END) AS sales_diff
    FROM OrderDetails odAll 
    INNER JOIN Orders oAll 
        ON oAll.OrderID = odAll.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products pAll
        ON odAll.ProductID =  pAll.ProductID
    GROUP BY pAll.ProductID
    ORDER BY sales
    LIMIT 3
)
ORDER BY
    marker,
    CASE WHEN marker = 0 THEN sales_diff ELSE -1*sales_diff END DESC;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use BETWEEN statement in the WHERE clause: WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-01' and '1996-10-31' w3schools.com/sql/sql_between.asp

```
    SELECT 
  od.ProductID, 
  MIN(o.OrderDate) as SalesStart, 
  MAX(o.OrderDate) as SalesEnd, 
  SUM(od.Quantity) as SoldQty, 
  SUM(od.Quantity * p.Price) as SoldAmt, 
  SUM(od.Quantity * p.Price) * 1.0 / 
  (
    SELECT SUM(odAll.Quantity * pAll.Price) 
    FROM OrderDetails odAll 
    INNER JOIN Orders as oAll 
      ON oAll.OrderID = odAll.OrderID
    INNER JOIN Products as pAll
      ON odAll.ProductID =  pAll.ProductID
    WHERE oAll.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-01' and '1996-10-31') as PortionInTotalSales
FROM Orders as o
INNER JOIN OrderDetails as od
  ON o.OrderID = od.OrderID
INNER JOIN Products as p
  ON od.ProductID =  p.ProductID  
WHERE o.OrderDate BETWEEN '1996-09-01' and '1996-10-31'
GROUP BY od.ProductID
```

Comment: Thank you, but I got a syntax error from w3c platform.

Comment: Think I missed a ')'  or something. I just ran this and it worked. Please try again